# How to insert into an array if its size is fixed?

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

I need to write such program:

```
The original elements of the array
20 34 45 2 10
Enter the index and number for insertion
3 12
Elements after insertion
20 34 45 12 2 10
```

I declare an array to store the initial numbers:

```
int array[5] = { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };
```

But how can I insert into this array?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at insertions in your code. Have you attempted anything so far? For a start, you certainly aren't going to insert anything to an array that you've sized at compile time and is already full.

Comment: You can't do that - arrays are fixed-size. Use a vector instead,.

Comment: You can make a new array of a size that can fit the previous contents and the new elements. Then copy over the previous contents to the new array and delete the old array.

Comment: @CoryKramer 


cout << "\n Enter the index and number for insertion\n";
cin >> index >> number;
/*i made it. but i couldnt this line 'insertion'*/
cout << "\n Elements after insertion \n";
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
cout << array[i] << "\t";
}
return 0;
}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO in not free coding service

Comment: @boriaz50: I am not sure I understand your edit(s) on this question. There was an initial attempt, and you seem to have removed it. That may have caused it to be found to be off-topic, and may cause it unfairly to attract downvotes it might not otherwise have received.

Comment: @halfer It was off-topic before my edits. I just try to save this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My answer was significantly changed.**

Of course, you cannot insert into this fixed-size array. And there is two ways to do what you need.

*The first way is allocating enough memory when you need it.* [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) successfully copes with this task.

```
vector<int> arr { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };

size_t index;
int number;

// input index and number

arr.insert(arr.begin() + index, number);
```

*The second way is reserving enough memory to store any potential number of elements.* In your case just reserve one more element to store being inserted number. It is preferable to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
const size_t N { 5 };
array<int, N + 1> arr { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };

size_t index;
int number;

// input index and number

for (size_t i = N; i > index; --i) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
}
arr[index] = number;
```

If you are forced to don't use C++11, replace

```
const size_t N { 5 };
array<int, N + 1> arr { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };
```

to

```
const size_t N = 5;
int arr[N + 1] = { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };
```

Note that such lab assignments often require user inputs data from keyboard. In this case, array size is known only at runtime and you are forced to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Note to OP - this "solution" doesn't do what you asked.

Comment: I significantly changed my answer. Can anyone review it and undownvote if possible, please?

Comment: @boriaz50: a weakness of the voting system is that voters are not notified of changes, so it is not possible to contact voters to ask them downvote. Perhaps your subsequent (20!) edits will attract new (up) voters.

Comment: my vote changed the score to zero, after 2 years! :D

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ are fixed in size, so an array of 5 ints cannot hold more than 5 ints as that is the amount of memory allocated for it and no more. 
You could look into other data structures like lists and vectors or you could declare your array to be large enough to hold all the objects you want. 
Here you might want to look into linked lists which make insertions without moving all the other elements possible.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ parlance, an 'array' is a c-style array, something
that should almost never be used. Use `std::vector` instead,
it has array-semantics (such as indexing with `[]`) plus
things like `insert` etc.

If what you have is fixed sized anyway, you might use `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // vector is just as convenient as an array to initialize
    vector<int> array = { 20, 34, 45, 2, 10 };

    cout << "The original elements of the array" << endl;
    // you can use range-based for loops with containers
    for (auto val : array)
        cout << val << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    int index;
    int number;

    cout << "Enter the index and number for insertion" << endl;
    cin >> index;
    cin >> number;

    // vector support insert, and many other operations
    array.insert( array.begin()+index, number );

    cout << "Elements after insertion" << endl;
    for (auto val : array)
        cout << val << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: [try it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddc9caa171ecc10c)